# Attaching movieclips along a path with rotation

Tags: actionscript-3

I´d like to know..

How would be a class, for attaching a movieclip along a path, with rotation?

Like:

In a mall map (top view)
How to make the movie clip 'foot steps', appear along a line (path) ?

A line that should start at a point in the map (entry) and end at another (store).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any class to do that.

1. Put your symbol (foot steps) on the stage
2. Righ-click on its layer and select "Add Classic motion guide"
3. Draw the path in the new guide layer with the pencil or the line
4. Create a keyframe on your symbol's layer at the end of the movement and a frame on the guide's layer
5. Right-click on the first frame of the symbol's layer and select "Create classic tween"
6. In the property panel tick "Orient to Path"
7. Make sure your clip is right on each end of the path at the begining and the end of the movement with the proper rotation

You're done!